# Trading View - Adding a custom time frame but they are not showing in chart and i want to hide time interval dropdown widget

Tags: angular, trading, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

Trading View - Adding a custom time frame  but they are not showing in  chart and  i want to hide time interval dropdown widget
[image]

I want to hide this time interval from chart with widget and marked all favorite time interval will show like this chart[image]

Answer (score 0):

pay attention to character units for timeframe text and resolution, text characters are lowercase but for resolution is uppercase more than minutes like 1D=1day:

```
time_frames: [
{ text: "1y", resolution: "1D", description: `1 ${t("year")}`, title: `1 ${t("year")}` },
{ text: "3m", resolution: "60", description: `3 ${t("month")}`, title: `3 ${t("month")}` },
{ text: "1m", resolution: "30", description: `1 ${t("month")}`, title: `1 ${t("month")}` },
{ text: "5d", resolution: "5", description: `5 ${t("day")}`, title: `5 ${t("day")}` },
{ text: "1d", resolution: "5", description: `1 ${t("day")}`, title: `1 ${t("day")}` },
] as TimeFrameItem[]
```